# Type JSON does not conform to protocol SecuenceType when trying to loop using SwiftyJSON in Swift

Tags: ios, json, loops, swift

im using SwiftyJSON library to parse my json responses in swift, but Xcode give this error and can't loop the array, here is my code:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://li.homeip.net:8091/query/search/", parameters: ["q": self.queryBox.text])

        .responseJSON{ (request, response, responseSphinx, error) in

            self.spinner.stopAnimating()
            self.spinner.alpha = 0

            let jsonSphinx = JSON(object: responseSphinx!)

            let resultados = jsonSphinx["matches"]

            println(resultados[1]["attrs"]["excerpt"]) // this works fine

            for el in resultados { // Error: Type JSON does not conform to protocol SecuenceType
                println(el)
            }
    }
```

Thanks, im new in swift.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#loop) says

```
for (index: String, el: JSON) in resultados {
    println(el)
}
```

should work for you. If this fails, you may need to update SwiftyJSON.

Alternatively, you can try

```
for el in resultados.arrayValue {
    println(el)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, in first loop Xcode says: Type JSON does not conform protocol Sequence Type, in second example Xcode says: Array Json does not have a member Generator... it could be my installation of SwiftyJSON?

Comment: @MikelDavidCarozziSanchez As a guess, I would say you have an old version or it's not linked into your project correctly. Both `SequenceType` and `arrayValue` are extensions. You could be running into a module/extension issue.

Comment: Thanks, i will check the installation of SwiftyJSON, for the issue mentionated, but about older version i don't think so, cause u clone the github repo yesterday. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid looping?  Can't you just define an array and then read array?